# Extracting specific cell value from Excel or Power BI

Tags: excel, powerbi, excel-2016

What approach would be recommended to extract only the first movie Genre from Excel.  I would like to add a Excel file to Power BI as a data set so that I can show film Genres.  I would like to display the first listed Genre in the cell without the other listings and information such as names and ID.  Here is a screenshot of 2 records as an example:

[image]

I will eventually merge on another data set by film name.  Is there a way to extract the first listed Genre?

The following formula used in Excel gave me an error:  =MID(A2,FIND("Name",A2,1)+8,FIND("""},",A2,1)-FIND("Name",A2,1)-8)

[image]

Comment: What you're showing there is JSON that just happens to be opened in excel. Try importing this into PowerBI as JSON. Which cell are you referring to here? A 'cell' in PowerBI? That could just be a drop down filter with the first entry showing. It's difficult to understand what you're really trying to do here

Comment: This is an Excel file which includes a mixture of JSON, Text and Number values in different columns (replaced original screenshot with another including other columns).  How would I go about importing and Excel file, not completely JSON, into Power BI?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract first movie genre from cell string, you can use this formula `=MID(A2,FIND("Name",A2,1)+8,FIND("""},",A2,1)-FIND("Name",A2,1)-8)` in cell `B2`. Drag formula to the bottom.

[image]

Comment: Not sure why but I am getting an #VALUE! error with the formula.  I noticed your screenshot was missing a ']' at the end, but it didn't matter because I tried with and without it included.  Is there some type of setting that I am missing for the formula?  Adding screenshot of formula error

Comment: replace "Name" with "name" inside formula. Find is case sensitive, and I used capital letter, my mistake :)

Comment: You reek of awesomeness, thanks so very much.  I should have taken that into account!